# Автономный режим веб-приложения

Tags: python, django

Есть готовое веб-приложение на Django

Пользователь пользуется системой на ios через safari (может еще chrome)

Юзер стори такой:

1. На первой странице пользователь_1 заполняет некоторые поля
2. Данные с формы отправляются постом на сервер в БД
3. На второй странице эти данные подтягиваются с сервера и верефицируются другим пользователем_2

(Оба пользователя используют для работы один планшет)

Собственно как перевести все это в автономный режим (без возможности отправлять запросы к серверу)?

1. На первой странице пользователь_1 заполняет некоторые поля
2. Данные с формы сохраняются локально
3. На второй странице эти данные подтягиваются с локального хранилища и верефицируются другим пользователем_2

Есть возможность хранить как-то все это локально, а когда появится интернет залить на сервер?

Comment: Наверное можно попробовать хранить все в куквх или сессиХ

Comment: Как же у вас сайт загрузится без интернета? Либо держать странички локально и с помощью JavaScript сохранять/подгружать файлы, а на сервере сделать простенький API - но это уж совсем костыли, Django к этим страничкам уже не будет иметь отношения. Либо сделать приложение для iOS для этих целей и также через API отправлять с него данные в ту же бд, которой пользуется сайт.

Comment: А можно сайт на джанго передеать в PWA? PWA подойдет для этих целей?

Answer (score 1):

Обмен данными, при отсутствии соединения с интернетом возможны благодаря `p2p`. Конкретно `Django` в этом никак не поможет.

Для Ваших целей может подойти некая промежуточная база данных, например `GunDB` или `OrbitDB`. Перед `submit` нужной вам формы, можно проверять на стороне клиента, есть ли соединение с интернетом, и если нет, то писать в эту промежуточную базу. На стороне же сервера подписываетесь на события этой промежуточной БД, и когда данные придут - вы их записываете в основную БД, например PostgreSQL